# Scrapy, await before pipeline

Tags: python, html, scrapy

(I'm new to scrapy).

### Context

Suppose there is a site `https://example.com` and I want to scrape it.

It is structured like this:

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        title_foo
        <a href="https://example.com/title_foo">a desription</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        title_bar
        <a href="https://example.com/title_bar">an another desription</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

following the `<a>` link, I can get a description that I need before creating my items and send them to my pipeline which will store them into my db.

For instance, let's say that when I follow https://example.com/title_foo, I retreive that description into

```
<div class="a-descrption">
    a description
</div>
```

In `items.py`, I've:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
```

And my spider should looks like that:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_project.items import MyItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://example.com',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.xpath('//li/text()').getall()
            yield {"title": li }
```

At least, I hope, I didn't tested it, correct me if something is wrong.

### Question

There is a kind of "await" mechanism here. I mean, I need to tell to scrapy to wait that  link has been visited before yielding my item. That seems to be a common problem and I'm sure that some practices exists in order to solve that problem but wasn't able to found how.

How do you do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the only field scraped is `title`, so I'm not entirely sure, but it sounds like you want to scrape the `title` at https://example.com, make a request to a detail page (like https://example.com/title_foo) scrape the description there and THEN `yield` the item with both the `description` and the `title`.

**If that's the case,** the common solution for this type of problem is to use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs) or meta. (*cb_kwargs are the recommended solution if you are using Scrapy v1.7+*)

`cb_kwargs` allows you to pass arbitrary data into the callback function of a request. It's important to note that the data is passed as a keyword argument. So for example:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"

    start_urls = ['https://example.com',]

    def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.xpath('//li'):
            title = li.xpath('text()').get()
            url_to_detail_page = li.xpath('a/@href').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url_to_detail_page,
                callback=self.parse_detail_page,
                cb_kwargs={
                    'title': title
                })

    def parse_detail_page(self, response, title):  # Notice title as a keyword arg
        description = response.xpath('//div[@class="a-descrption"]//text()').getall()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'description': description,
        }
```

Here the data scraped at the first page, stored into `title`, "accompanies" the request to the detail page and when the callback function is called `title` is received as an argument, so you can access it from the function.